# ASP.NET function wont return value from for loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Im trying to return value from function which should return Dictionary after going throught while loop. Problem is loop goes only once and when I try debug this the breakpoint at return wont it wont even fire up. No exception if fired up.

```
public async Task<Dictionary<TimeSpan, TimeSpan>> GetTimes(int id)
        {
            Dictionary<TimeSpan, TimeSpan> hours = new Dictionary<TimeSpan, TimeSpan>();
            var room = await GetRoom(id);
            int i = room.Open;
            while (i < room.Close)
            {
                TimeSpan from = TimeSpan.FromHours(i);
                TimeSpan to = TimeSpan.FromHours(++i);

                hours.Add(from, from);
                hours.Add(from, to);           
            }

            return hours;
        }
```

function it self is calling from Controler.

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> CreateReserve(DateTime dateTime,int id)
    {
        if(dateTime >=  DateTime.Now)
        {
            return PartialView("RoomCount", await _room.GetTimes(id));
        }

        return PartialView("Reservations");
    }
```

Action from controller is called from view

````
<input class="form-control col-sm-5" onchange="SetTime({ value:this.value,id: @Model.Id })" type="date" value="@DateTime.Today.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")" />

<script>function SetTime({value,id}) {
    @*$.post("/Home/CreateReserve", { dateTime: value });*@
    $("#reservations").load("/Home/CreateReserve",{ dateTime: value,id: id });
}
    </script>
    ```
````

Comment: The description is a bit confusing.  You say you observe that the loop iterates exactly once, but that the `return` line is never reached?  Then what happens after you observe the loop iterating?  Is an exception being thrown?

Comment: @David Hey according to the debugger, the application passes only once through the loop but no exception is thrown and the breakpoint on return is not assigned.

Comment: Might need to show the `Room` object and the `GetRoom` method

Comment: @fikus: It honestly sounds like there's a mistake or false assumption in the debugging then.  Maybe somehow the debugger is attached to an older version of the code?  Try cleaning the build, closing Visual Studio, etc.  Because if the step debugger exits the `while` loop but *doesn't* move on to the `return` statement (and no exception was thrown) then something is wrong with the debugging, not with the code.

Comment: As an aside, I'm kind of *surprised* that an exception isn't being thrown.  Because it looks like you're adding two items to the dictionary with the same key...

Comment: Add a try/catch around that code, to *really* see whether there is an exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> No exception if fired up.

Yes there is.  Right here:

```
hours.Add(from, to);
```

> Problem is loop goes only once and when I try debug this the breakpoint at return wont it wont even fire up.

Because the last line of the loop throws an exception.  Control exits the method.  The calling method doesn't catch exceptions, so control exits that too.  The problem here is that you're not *observing the result* of the operation.  Go back to your browser's debugging tools and see that the AJAX operation returned a result, and that result was an error.  (When developing web applications, it's a good idea to use your IDE for debugging the server-side code and rely on your browser's debugging tools for the client-side code.)

So for one thing, you'll need to add some better error handling both server-side and client-side so you can observe these things.

More to the point, what's happening here is that you're adding two elements to the `Dictionary<>` with the same key:

```
hours.Add(from, from);
hours.Add(from, to);
```

Dictionary keys *must* be unique (or, more specifically, produce unique hash codes).  It's not entirely clear what data structure you're trying to create here or for what purpose, but what is clear is that you can't add two elements to a `Dictionary<>` with the same key.

Maybe you want a list of custom objects instead?  Or use some other value as the key?  Something else?  That's really up to you and the domain you're modeling in the application.

Comment: Thanks for tip. I am going to try. Its school asigment project and here im trying to return list of open hours so for example when is open from 8 - 19 i want to return 
list where would be 8-9 then 9-10 10-11 etc. I was thinking that Dictionary works like Hash in Ruby.